# Bochner Integral: Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider a continuous derivative:
$$F'\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},E):\quad\int_\mathbb{R}\|F'(s)\|\mathrm{d}s<\infty$$

Then its integral computes as:
$$\int_a^bF'(s)\mathrm{d}s=F(b)-F(a)$$
How to prove this by modern tools?

Comment: Please clarify: it seems you'd like to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus in the case that the target space is a Banach space, using a particular set of methods you refer to as "modern tools".  What do you mean by "modern tools"?

Comment: Can we assume an appropriate version of the mean value theorem, or does that need to be proven from scratch?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: My excuses: By modern tools I meant functional analytic methods. Then mean value theorem is perfectly fine, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual proof works, i.e. define

$$
G : [a,\infty) \to E, x\mapsto \int_a^x F'(s) \, ds.
$$

Using (only) the definition of the derivative and the continuity of $F'$, it is easy to see that $G$ is differentiable with $G' = F' = H'$ for $H(x) := F(x) - F(a)$.

Since also $H(0) = G(0) = 0$, we conclude $H = G$ on $[a,\infty)$ (see below). But this implies your claim.

To see $H = G$, one possibility is to assume $H(x) \neq G(x)$ for some $x$. Since $E$ is a Banach space (hence locally convex), the bounded (real valued) linear functionals seperate poins, i.e. there is some $\varphi \in E'$ with $\varphi(H(x)) \neq \varphi(G(x))$.

But the chain rule yields $(\varphi \circ H) ' = (\varphi \circ G)'$, which contradicts the classical mean value theorem (for differentiable functions $f : I \to \Bbb{R}$).

Comment: Thanks!! That was the answer I was hoping for. =D

Comment: Aaaaahhh got it: $f'(x)\equiv0\implies f(x)\equiv f(0)$

Comment: Honestly, I never expected that Hahn-Banach is that powerful tool!! *(Literally, I've seen it almost everywhere.)*